# Saving masked image as FITS

Tags: python, mask, astropy, fits

I've constructed an image from some FITS files, and I want to save the resultant masked image as another FITS file. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from astropy.nddata import CCDData
from ccdproc import CCDData

hdulist1 = fits.open('wise_neowise_w1-MJpersr.fits')
hdulist2 = fits.open('wise_neowise_w2-MJpersr.fits')

data1_raw = hdulist1[0].data
data2_raw = hdulist2[0].data

#   Hide negative values in order to take logs
#   Where {condition}==True, return data_raw, else return np.nan
data1 = np.where(data1_raw >= 0, data1_raw, np.nan)
data2 = np.where(data2_raw >= 0, data2_raw, np.nan)

#   Calculation and image subtraction
w1mag = -2.5 * (np.log10(data1) - 9.0)
w2mag = -2.5 * (np.log10(data2) - 9.0)
color = w1mag - w2mag

##   Find upper and lower 5th %ile of pixels
mask_percent = 5
masked_value_lower = np.nanpercentile(color, mask_percent)
masked_value_upper = np.nanpercentile(color, (100 - mask_percent))

##   Mask out the upper and lower 5% of pixels
##   Need to hide values outside the range [lower, upper]
color_masked = np.ma.masked_outside(color, masked_value_lower, masked_value_upper)
color_masked = np.ma.masked_invalid(color_masked)

plt.imshow(color)
plt.title('color')
plt.savefig('color.png', overwrite = True)
plt.imshow(color_masked)
plt.title('color_masked')
plt.savefig('color_masked.png', overwrite = True)

fits.writeto('color.fits',
             color,
             overwrite = True)
ccd = CCDData(color_masked, unit = 'adu')
ccd.write('color_masked.fits', overwrite = True))

hdulist1.close()
hdulist2.close()
```

When I use `matplotlib.pyplot` to `imshow` the images `color` and `color_masked`, they look as I expect:
[image]
[image]
However, my two output files, color_masked.fits == color.fits. I think somehow I'm not quite understanding the masking process properly. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Is your primary concern to **save the mask** or to use another program (unrelated to python/matplotlib) to display the FITS files with mask (e.g. IRAF, MIDAS or DS9)?

Comment: My next step is to fit a mathematical model to the un-masked portion of the image, so I guess I don't really need to save the mask. On the other hand, I'm doing it as a project for my MSc and I'm hoping to be able to show my supervisor my intermediate images in DS9.

Comment: But for the purpose of this question: You want DS9 to display the image without masked pixels?

Comment: Oh, then the answer is yes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`astropy.io.fits` only handles normal arrays and that means it just ignores/discards the `mask` of your `MaskedArray`.

Depending on your use-case you have different options:

### Saving the file so other FITS programs recognize the mask

I actually don't think that's possible. But some programs like DS9 can handle `NaN`s, so you could just set the masked values to `NaN` for the purpose of displaying them:

```
data_naned = np.where(color_masked.mask, np.nan, color_masked)
fits.writeto(filename, data_naned, overwrite=True)
```

They do still show up as "bright white spots" but they don't affect the color-scale.

If you want to take this a step further you could replace the masked pixels using a convolution filter before writing them to a file. Not sure if there's one in `astropy` that only replaces masked pixels though.

### Saving the mask as extension so you can read them back

You could use [`astropy.nddata.CCDData`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.CCDData.html) (available since astropy 2.0) to save it as FITS file with mask:

```
from astropy.nddata import CCDData

ccd = CCDData(color_masked, unit='adu')
ccd.write('color_masked.fits', overwrite=True)
```

Then the mask will be saved in an extension called `'MASK'` and it can be read using `CCDData` as well:

```
ccd2 = CCDData.read('color_masked.fits')
```

The `CCDData` behaves like a masked array in normal NumPy operations but you could also convert it to a masked-array by hand:

```
import numpy as np
marr = np.asanyarray(ccd2)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, MSeifert. Trying to install CCDData in Anaconda results in PackageNotFoundError. There is a package called ccdproc, but that doesn't seem to have the same functionality as CCDData. Has the package been replaced by something?

Comment: @Jim421616 It's part of `astropy`, like the `astropy.io.fits` module you're using. If you have a recent version of astropy it should be importable using `from astropy.nddata import CCDData`. If you don't have a recent astropy version you can also update astropy with conda using `conda install astropy=2`.

Comment: @Jim421616 Historically it has been part of the `ccdproc` package so if you don't want (or can) upgrade you could use `conda install -c conda-forge ccdproc` and use `from ccdproc import CCDData` instead.

Comment: Those are very helpful comments; I've edited my post to include your ideas. color_masked is still showing the pixels I'm trying to mask though. I've tried importing CCDData from both astropy.nddata and from ccdproc (after following your installation instructions). Am I doing something wrong in using ccddata?

Comment: @Jim421616 Thanks for the clarification. It seems like I originally misunderstood your question. I updated the answer. It's a bit "ugly" but based on my DS9 viewer it works. The masked values still show up as bright white spots but they don't affect the color-scale anymore which gives much more contrast.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can use the mask again when I fit the model.